# Vector VS Array Databases (Theoretically Question)

Tags: database, nosql

The question is what are the key differences between vector and array databases.

To my understanding, vector databases seem to be a subset of array databases.

Vector databases are specifically for saving, indexing and querying vectors/embeddings (perhaps, stemmed from ML/AI models) whereas array databases appear to be able to handle more generic array-like data such as pixel of images, multidimensional data/arrays and etc.

What is your take on the issue?

Thank you in advance

PS: certainly I have already googled/prompted LLms for an answer but it is kind of perplexing.